# SQLALchemy update ARRAY column

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a Post model table like this:

```
class Base(Post):
  ...
  liked_users = Column(ARRAY(Integer))
  ...
```

I can not add new element to this column using this way:

```
post = db.query(DbPost).filter(DbPost.id == 1).first()

#print(post.liked_users) => [1,2]


post.liked_users.append(5)
db.commit()
```

Here I can not add 5 to the column liked_users. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to try the `MutableList` class from the [mutable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mutable.html) extension.

Comment: snakecharmerb, yes I found the answer. Thank you!